# How to filter an array based on a nested array 4 level deep?

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
let accessArray = [{
      id: 1,
      restrictions: [{
         canAccess: true,
         users: [{
            name: 'user',
            accessLevel: [10, 20, 30]
         }]
      }]
   },
   {
      id: 2,
      restrictions: [{
         canAccess: true,
         users: [{
            name: 'user2',
            accessLevel: [10, 20]
         }]
      }]
   }
]
```

I would like to know how I filter to get only the `accessArray` items that contains the `accessLevel` **30** which in the example is the item with `id = 1`.Thanks.

Comment: Looking like, this is invalid JS Object, have you tried anything?

Comment: arrays do not have key-value pairs

Comment: Is it possible that the restrictions array will have more than one items you have to check?

Comment: Yes, all the arrays can have more than one element, i put with one to simplify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the restrictions and users arrays can have multiple elements, not always just one, so you can do this :

```js
let accessArray = [{
    id: 1,
    restrictions: [{
      canAccess: true,
      users: [{
        name: 'user',
        accessLevel: [10, 20, 30]
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    restrictions: [{
      canAccess: true,
      users: [{
        name: 'user2',
        accessLevel: [10, 20]
      }]
    }]
  }
]

let output = accessArray.filter( obj =>
  obj.restrictions.some( restriction =>
    restriction.users.some( user =>
      user.accessLevel.includes(30)
    )
  )
)

console.log(output)
```

In this example, it returns true if *any* of the users has accessLevel 30. If you need *all* users to have accessLevel 30, then replace `.some` with `.every`.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a nested [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const accessArray = [{id:1,restrictions:[{canAccess:true,users:[{name:'user',accessLevel:[10,20,30]}]}]},{id:2,restrictions:[{canAccess:true,users:[{name:'user2',accessLevel:[10,20]}]}]}]

const level = 30;

function getAccess(level) {
  return accessArray.filter(a => 
              a.restrictions.some(b => 
                  b.users.some(c => c.accessLevel.includes(level))))
}

console.log(getAccess(30))
```

(This assumes that the nested arrays at least empty `[]` and none of them are `null` or `undefined`)

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate all objects and look for the wanted key and of this value is an array, then check for the value, otherwise call the function again for all other found objects.

This works without knowing the path to the wanted nested property. It works for any depth.

```js
const
    has = (key, value) => function iter(o) {
        return Object.entries(o).some(([k, v]) => 
            k === key && Array.isArray(v) && v.includes(value) ||
            v && typeof v === 'object' && iter(v)
        );
    };

var array = [{ id: 1, restrictions: [{ canAccess: true, users: [{ name: 'user', accessLevel: [10, 20, 30] }] }] }, { id: 2, restrictions: [{ canAccess: true, users: [{ name: 'user2', accessLevel: [10, 20] }] }] }],
    result = array.filter(has('accessLevel', 30));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter function to only return what you want:

```js
let accessArray = [{
    id: 1,
    restrictions: [{
      canAccess: true,
      users: [{
        name: 'user',
        accessLevel: [10, 20, 30]
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    restrictions: [{
      canAccess: true,
      users: [{
        name: 'user2',
        accessLevel: [10, 20]
      }]
    }]
  }
]

console.log(accessArray.filter(a => a.restrictions.some(b => b.users.some( c => c.accessLevel.includes(30)))))
```

Comment: It works with this particular example, but I suspect the `restrictions` and `users` arrays can have multiple elements, not always just one

Comment: I've updated to reflect OP's comments. This is why people need to be clear when asking questions... The original dataset wasn't even valid javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This will check multiple users in multiple restriction objects

```
accessArray.filter(arr => {
    return arr.restrictions.filter(re => {
        return re.users.filter(user => user.accessLevel.includes(30)).length>0;
    }).length>0;
})
```

Or in a single line

```
accessArray.filter(arr => arr.restrictions.filter(re => re.users.filter(user => user.accessLevel.includes(30)).length>0).length>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
accessArray.filter(arr => arr.restrictions.filter(re => re.users.filter(user => user.accessLevel.includes(30))))
```